# How can I manage DNS records on Openstack using Pulumi?

Tags: dns, openstack, pulumi

Last month I started using Pulumi to manage an infrastructure on OVH which is using Openstack.
Everything when fine until I needed to add the IP of my newly created instance in a RecordSet in a DNS Zone.

First of all I set all these Openstack environment variables as recommended by sourcing the `open-rc.sh` file, which was generated from a user in OVH which has Administrator role :

```
OS_REGION_NAME
OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID
OS_INTERFACE
OS_AUTH_URL
OS_USERNAME
OS_PROJECT_ID
OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME
OS_PROJECT_NAME
OS_PASSWORD
OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION
```

Then, I tried the example of the documentation from here https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/openstack/dns/recordset/ :

```
import pulumi
import pulumi_openstack as openstack

example_zone = openstack.dns.Zone("exampleZone",
    description="a zone",
    email="email2@example.com",
    ttl=6000,
    type="PRIMARY")
rs_example_com = openstack.dns.RecordSet("rsExampleCom",
    description="An example record set",
    records=["10.0.0.1"],
    ttl=3000,
    type="A",
    zone_id=example_zone.id)
```

But then I get the following error :

```
Updating (dev_stack_s3_linux):
     Type                   Name                                  Status                  Info
     pulumi:pulumi:Stack    test_pulumi_linux-dev_stack_s3_linux  **failed**              1 error
 +   └─ openstack:dns:Zone  exampleZone                           **creating failed**     1 error

Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (test_pulumi_linux-dev_stack_s3_linux):
    error: update failed

  openstack:dns:Zone (exampleZone):
    error: Error creating OpenStack DNS client: No suitable endpoint could be found in the service catalog.

Resources:
    1 unchanged

Duration: 7s
```

I looked around and I found that Openstack has it's own client Designate to manage DNS records. Moreover, when I do `openstack catalog list` there is no DNS service there.

Is this possible to manage DNS records from Pulumi ? It is in the official documentation and it doesn't seem like anybody encountered this problem so I think I am missing something there.